# Bluemix Schedule App Stop & Start

Tags: ibm-cloud, scheduling, cloud-foundry

Anyone know if we can set a schedule to start-stop apps on Bluemix?

We are basically looking for ways to reduce our footprint by shutting down internal application out of hours.

We understand there's a feature on Azure ([Auzre Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/automation-intro/)) which can facilitate this, does anyone know if Bluemix has an equivalent?

Else another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything 'out of the box' in BlueMix to do this. There are numerous ways you can solve this with the primitives that Cloud Foundry provides, the simplest being a script on a CI server that enumerates apps in a space and calls `cf stop` on each of them.

The [Cloud Controller API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/245/) will help you, as will using the `cf curl` command. Alternatively you could write a script in something like Ruby, and use that to parse returned JSON.

Comment: Using some CI controller that fires these up using the Cloud Foundry CLI, and then shuts them down, is probably your best bet.  Once you get the basics figured out, you should be able to easily make parameters for start time, stop time, app name, app path and environment - which will make this really easy to maintain.